# PowerShell is not splitting param

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script (below) which accepts an argument (string) and then splits it. For some reason, the code below doesn't work unless I use an intermediate variable like so. My question - why is that the case?

> $name2 = $name.Split(" ")

```
function New-Name {

    param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $name
    )

    $name = $name.Split(" ")

    Write-Debug $name

    if( $name.Count -gt 1 ) {
        Write-Debug "2+"
    }
    else {
        Write-Debug "1"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because you're declaring `$name` as `string` but `$name.Split(" ")` returns an array.

Comment: Type casting is not possible in this case?

Comment: No, can't type cast. But you can redefine `[string[]] $name = $name.Split(" ")` But keep in mind, I'm not a powershell developer and I only tested in console. It may have better ways I'm not aware of.

Comment: You can also declare $name as array at the beginning. But In that case you will accept multiple parameters [demo on tio.run](https://tio.run/##RY6xCsMwDER3fYViMjiQ9g@yd2mWBjqEDKZRW4NjG8UmhNJvd1MHWi13PB06ebcQz08yJqV7tLegncWWlkOrJsIXAG7jFatJZttnT4FYnpUdVXC8NmXHkaphD8yBtX30w4Cl3ZIZVvudDLDZ9XjxRgcpUFT/JcAb4FcvTttfrsarYzMWov6CFVcXCwEpfQA)

Answer (score 3):

As cbaconnier says: `.Split()` returns an array of substrings.
For instance, if you have:

```
$name = 'John Doe'
$firstname = $name.Split(" ")[0]  # returns "John"
$lastname  = $name.Split(" ")[1]  # returns "Doe"
```

Instead of using the .Net `.Split()` method, you could also do the PowerShell `-split` which uses regular expression and has the advantage of doing the above in one go:

```
$name = 'John Doe'
$firstname, $lastname = $name -split ' '
```

Have a look at the [String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) for the many overloads you can use and also look at [About Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6).

Hope that explains @cbaconnier answer